# Spring Custom Properties File Under Subfolder Read in The Application Start

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi I have a custom properties file.And I have a aspect and it has condition.If my.properties under resource directly PropertySourcesPropertyResolver read myproperties and find it in applicationstart process.How can I force my properties file under subfolder read by propertysourcespropertyresolver

```
 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'myenable' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
```

But When I add subfolder in resource like Resource/myfolder/my.properties that time PropertySourcesPropertyResolver cannot resolve it at the beginning

```
@Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:/myfolder/my.properties")
    public class MyConfigProperties

 private String myenable;

....

@Service
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${myenable}'=='true'")
public class MyAspect
```

Comment: are you putting this annotation @PropertySource("classpath:/myfolder/my.properties")
on any @Configuration annoted  class ?

Comment: yes,it has @configuration also

Comment: Add `@PropertySource("classpath:/myfolder/my.properties")` below `@SpringBootApplication` . it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

**@PropertySource** will work only if you put this annotation on a configuration class(annotated with @Configuration or any other annotation extending @Configuration like @SpringBootApplication, @SpringBootConfiguration etc.).

In your case annotate your class **MyConfigPropertie** with @Configuration along with @PropertySource

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/myfolder/my.properties")
@Configuration
public class MyConfigPropertie {

}
```

OR

put this **@PropertySource("classpath:/myfolder/my.properties")** on spring main class annotated with  **@SpringBootApplication**

Comment: @Configuration already exist .but not working ,MyAspect cant see this value at the beginning